# Blender UV project missing Image?

Tags: uv, modifiers, uv-image-editor

I was recently doing a Project needing the UV project modifier, but the Image selection menu appears to be missing as of Blender 2.8. I have attached both 2.8 and 2.79 screenshots to show you what I mean, Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that image option and override was used only for blender internal rendering.
2.8 does not have that render engine any more, so there is no need for those options in the modifier.

The  functions didn't have any effect in cycles. The images have to be part of the textures connected to shaders.

Read the answer and the comments on the link.

[Image setting in UV Project Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/image-setting-in-uv-project-modifier)